# Why isn't Yarn installing Node?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a very simple `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "node": "^8.0.0",
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "which node"
  }
}
```

But, when I run `yarn install && yarn test` it points me to my system version of node and `node` is not installed in `node_modules/.bin/`.

With `npm`, on the other hand, `node` is installed in `node_modules/.bin/` and that version is used:

```
> npm install && npm run test
.../node_modules/.bin/node
```

Once a local version of `node` is installed by `npm`, `yarn` will use it.

How can I get `yarn` to install `node`?

Comment: This is a an important issue, and since this is an issue, it makes sense to open one.

Comment: Why don't you use `nvm` if you're trying to install multiple versions of node?

Comment: Nvm is an external dependency that would require additional setup and work to ensure that everyone is using the same version of node.